# DomainKeys Sendmail DNS

Tags: dns, sendmail, domainkeys

What steps do I have to take to configure my sendmail server to implement domainkeys properly?

Also what do I have to do on the DNS end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are detailed descriptions on the web. For example:

- http://www.elandsys.com/resources/sendmail/domainkeys.html
- http://www.erikberg.com/notes/milters.html
- http://www.technoids.org/dk-milter.html/

Answer (score 0):

I had success with dkfilter.
On the dns side you need to setup 3 TXT entries:

```
(blank).domain.com                   value="YOUR-SPF-CODE-HERE" 
                                     (get your spf code at openspf.org)
_sldomain.domain.com                 value="o=~"
yourselector._sldomain.domain.com    value="YOUR-PUBLIC-DOMAIN-KEY"
```

Generate your public domain key like shown in this tutorial: 
http://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_dkfilter_domain_keys_implementation

Download dkfilter here:
http://jason.long.name/dkfilter/